# Combine datasets of multiple HDF5 files into a virtual dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have several HDF5 files that contain the same two datasets each, `data` and `labels`. These datasets are multidimensional arrays and the first is dimension is the same for both.

I would like to combine the HDF5 files into one file and I think the best way would be to create a virtual dataset, [[h5py reference](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/663)], [[HDF5 tutorial in C++](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/vds.html)]. However, I have not found any example in Python and h5py.

Is there any alternative to the virtual dataset or do you know of any example using h5py?

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question but anyway...

Virtual datasets have only just appeared (20 Dec 2018) fully in [h5py v2.9](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/whatsnew/2.9.html)

They have this example of creating a virtual dataset:
https://github.com/h5py/h5py/blob/master/examples/vds_simple.py

I also did some experimenting to concatenate the data sets that the example creates.
This just creates a 1D array.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

file_names_to_concatenate = ['1.h5', '2.h5', '3.h5', '4.h5']
entry_key = 'data' # where the data is inside of the source files.

sources = []
total_length = 0
for i, filename in enumerate(file_names_to_concatenate):
    with h5py.File(file_names_to_concatenate[i], 'r') as activeData:
        vsource = h5py.VirtualSource(activeData[entry_key])
        total_length += vsource.shape[0]
        sources.append(vsource)

layout = h5py.VirtualLayout(shape=(total_length,),
                            dtype=np.float)

offset = 0
for vsource in sources:
    length = vsource.shape[0]
    layout[offset : offset + length] = vsource
    offset += length

with h5py.File("VDS_con.h5", 'w', libver='latest') as f:
    f.create_virtual_dataset(entry_key, layout, fillvalue=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

take **gdal virtual format** for a try.

- python gdal website: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/index.html
- gdal virtual format tutorial: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html

Comment: GDAL does not seem to support HDF5

Comment: @sappjw it's not original supported, taking libhdf5 dll in compiling will be useful: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html

Answer (score 0):

Someone has tried it. Example is here, but unfortunately I was not able to get it to work and also it seems to be syntactically incorrect. https://github.com/aaron-parsons/h5py/blob/1e467f6db3df23688e90f44bde7558bde7173a5b/docs/vds.rst#using-the-vds-feature-from-h5py

```
f = h5py.File("VDS.h5", 'w', libver='latest')
file_names_to_concatenate = ['1.h5', '2.h5', '3.h5', '4.h5', '5.h5']
entry_key = 'data' # where the data is inside of the source files.
sh = h5.File(file_names_to_concatenate[0],'r')[entry_key].shape # get the first ones shape.

TGT = h5.VirtualTarget(outfile, outkey, shape=(len(file_names_to_concatenate, ) + sh)

for i in range(num_projections):
    VSRC = h5.VirtualSource(file_names_to_concatenate[i]), entry_key, shape=sh)
    VM = h5.VirtualMap(VSRC[:,:,:], TGT[i:(i+1):1,:,:,:],dtype=np.float)
    VMlist.append(VM)

d = f.create_virtual_dataset(VMlist=VMlist,fillvalue=0)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not in the official version of h5py and I could not get it to work with that branch. Have you tried it? Did it work for you?

Comment: Sorry, I tried but failed. Updated my answer accordingly.